# Angular conditional content project

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent, angular-content-projection

I'm using Angular 16.

I have to create a component to render the multi-stepper components and the component usage will be like

```html
<!- app.component.html -->

<app-multi-step>
  <app-multi-step-panel title="Basic">
    <ng-template panelContent>
       <div>Panel content</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template panelFooter>
      <button (click)="handleNext()">Next</button>
    </ng-template>
  </app-multi-step-panel>

  <app-multi-step-panel title="Settings">
    <ng-template panelContent>
       <div>Settings content</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template panelFooter>
      <button (click)="handleNext()">Next</button>
    </ng-template>
  </app-multi-step-panel>
</app-multi-step>
```

Where the `app-multi-step` can have n-number of `app-multi-step-panel` which can have two directives `panelContent` to render contents and `panelFooter` to render footer content.

To achieve this, I created a component `multi-step`

```js
# multi-step.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi-step',
  templateUrl: './multi-step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multi-step.component.scss']
})
export class MultiStepComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(MultiStepPanelComponent) panels: QueryList<MultiStepPanelComponent>;

  panelList: Array<string> = [];

  projectedIndex = 0;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.panelList = this.panels.map(p => p.title);
  }

  setProjection(index) {
    this.projectedIndex = index;
  }
}
```

and the HTML content

```html
<!-- multi-step.component.html -->

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="multisteps-form__progress">
      <button [disabled]="i > projectedIndex" (click)="setProjection(i)" class="multisteps-form__progress-btn" [class.js-active]="i <= projectedIndex" type="button" title="{{panelTitle}}" *ngFor="let panelTitle of panelList; let i=index">
        {{panelTitle}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 m-auto">
    <ng-content select="app-multi-step-panel"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working as expected, except I want to render one `app-multi-select-panel` at once and change the component based on the `projectIndex` value change.

How can I achieve it using the above setup? Any other approach suggestion is welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag called "selected" in "app-multi-step-panel" component, the component will be displayed only if the selected is true. In the "app-multi-step" component, make the selected flag of "app-multi-step-panel" in first index to be true. Likewise, have a UI in "app-multi-step" to change the index

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a variable "selectedIndex", then each button you change the value of the variable

```
<button *ngFor="let bt of panelList;let i=index" 
       (click)="select(i)">pannels</button>

@ViewChild(MultiStepComponent) pannelList:QueryList<MultiStepComponent>

select(index:number)
{
     this.selectedIndex=index
}
```

Then you can use style.display none or null depending the variable

```
<app-multi-step-panel title="Basic" 
     [style.display]="selectedIndex!=0?'none':null">
<app-multi-step-panel title="Settings" 
     [style.display]="selectedIndex!=1?'none':null">
...
```

But really, force to write style.display is an "ugly patchwork". Why not make that all was more scalable?

For this, first we are going to inject in constructor of the app-multi-step-panel the app-multi-step using [Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) and add a property index to our app-multi-step-panel

```
index:number=-1;
constructor(@Host() private parent:MultiStepComponent ){}
```

Then we can use HostBinding to give "style.display:none"

```
@HostBinding('style.display') get display() { 
   return !this.parent || this.parent.selectedIndex!=this.index ? 'none': null; }
```

The last piece of the jigsaw if give value of the "index" to our app-multi-step-panel from the app-multi-step

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.panelList.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>x.index=index)
}
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1j1g5g?file=src%2Fmain.ts)