# how to reset the styles of listitems in onlick event in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am new to angular

I have a list of items, so when I click the item its elements should be displayed and the item color should change. This the scenario.

I tried but there is not much material on this subject.

The code

```
<ul #topicContent>
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroArray;let i=index;" >
<li (click)="Expanded=Expanded==i?-1:i;  createComponent()"    appTopicexpand>
    Topic {{i}}
    <ul [hidden]="Expanded!=i?true:null" >
      <app-topiccontent></app-topiccontent>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

`

This the directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2, 
ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { TopicsmenuComponent } from 
'./topicsmenu/topicsmenu.component';

@Directive({
selector: '[appTopicexpand]'
})
export class TopicexpandDirective {
constructor(private _element:ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }
@HostListener ('click', ['$event']) onTopicClick(e: Event){
alert('you clicked the '+ this._element.nativeElement.innerText);
this._renderer.setStyle(this._element.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
}
}
`
```

This code only changes the color of the item itself but can't reset the css of all the items to default. To get all the items there must be @viewchildren kind of thing but not sure how to do here.

I want to know, how can I get all the list items in the event handler if possible.
There is no mention about such kind of situation in angular docs itself, also nothing about event handling in angular in details other than simple bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the **@ViewChildren** decorator to query all of the elements with the **appTopicexpand** directive.
2. In your click handler, loop over all of the queried elements and reset their styles to the default.
3. After resetting all of the styles, set the style of the clicked element to the active style.

The implementation would look like this:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TopicsmenuComponent } from './topicsmenu/topicsmenu.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTopicexpand]'
})
export class TopicexpandDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  // Array to store references to all instances of the ElementRef injected into the directive instances
  static elems: ElementRef[] = [];

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Push all intances to array
    TopicexpandDirective.elems.push(this._element);
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onTopicClick(e: Event) {
    alert('you clicked the ' + this._element.nativeElement.innerText);

    // Reset the styles of all elements to the default
    for (let el of TopicexpandDirective.elems) {
      this._renderer.setStyle(el.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'white');
    }

    // Set the style of the clicked element to the active style
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._element.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help. That was smart. Now, I wonder how to get the elements if I wanted to in the click event.  How can that be done with @viewchildren. 
Is there any good material on the subject i can study?

Comment: Please explain better your goal, and maybe I can help.

Comment: I mean, how can i get each list item in the click event, if i want to with @viewchildren. plus, where can I study the event handling in angular on advance level?

Comment: I think than, better that use renderer.setStyles, you can use `HostListener`, some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099922/angular-conditional-content-project/77102981#77102981)